# Load image from plist setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: image) error

Tags: uitableview

Please, can anyone help me with this error I received while practising an IOS App in Xcode 5

```
2014-03-16 14:10:44.072 TabCreator[563:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: image).
```

The images where loaded in images.xcassets and I created a plist file and was trying to populate the UITableView with an array in the plist as:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>pic</key>
        <string>skyline.png</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Skyline</string>
        <key>datecreated</key>
        <date>1975-06-03T23:00:00Z</date>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>pic</key>
        <string>hummer.png</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Hummer</string>
        <key>datecreated</key>
        <date>1963-12-18T00:00:00Z</date>
    </dict>

    </array>
</plist>
```

and my HomeviewController.m file is:

```
@interface HomeViewController ()
@property   (nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *functions;
@end

@implementation FTHomeViewController

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {

        NSString *plistPath =[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"functions" ofType:@"plist"];
        NSArray *nonMutableFunctions = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

        self.functions = [NSMutableArray array];

        NSMutableDictionary *function;
        NSDictionary *dictionary;
        NSString *name;
        NSString *pic;
        UIImage *image;
        NSDate *datecreated;

        for (int i=0; i<[nonMutableFunctions count]; i++) {
            dictionary = [nonMutableFunctions objectAtIndex:i];
            name=dictionary[@"name"];
            pic=dictionary[@"pic"];
            image=[UIImage imageNamed:pic];
            datecreated =dictionary[@"datecreated"];
            function = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

            function[@"name"]=name;
            function[@"image"]=image;
            function[@"datecreated"]=datecreated;

            [self.functions addObject:function];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    NSMutableDictionary *function=self.functions[indexPath.row];

    NSString *name =function[@"name"];
    NSDate *datecreated = function[@"datecreated"];
    UIImage *image = function[@"image"];

    cell.textLabel.text = name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = datecreated.description;
    cell.imageView.image = image;

    return cell;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [self.functions count];
}

//Deselect selected row when selected

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
@end
```

Would really appreciate it if anyone can help me out. Thanks

Comment: Basically, what it tells you is that your UIImage does not get created and you have nil in the image variable. Check your pic, dictionary and nonMutableFunctions vars.

Comment: Sorry for replying late. Thanks Krafter, had to debug it and found out that indeed the image variable is nil though the plist file does parse. Had to do some digging and found out that Xcode 5 images.xcassets doesn't really accept .JPG image extensions so had to do preview and export to .PNG without hiding the extension and it worked. Anyways, thanks for the input.

Comment: Didn't know the JPG images.xcassets issue. Thanks for letting me know. You may want to add an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple omitting of the png extension when I exported from jpg to png in preview. Had to leave it with the extension because the plots file contains the full file name including the extension.